# Indian Rupee Symbol

Tags: macos, keyboard

On OS X, Shift-Option-2 prints the Euro symbol **€**.

Is there a shortcut to print the Indian Rupee Symbol **₹**?

Comment: You need to specify what keyboard you are using. QUERTY, QWERTZ others ? just read the 6 letters starting at Q.

Comment: Buscar: QWERTZ, AZERTY, what ever the first row of your keyboard is... It does not tell you anything interessting about the rest of the keyboard layout. Especially when it comes to modified keys. Besides, knowing that Alt-Shift-2 results in €, you could already guess what layout it is.

Comment: Well the Alt-Shift-2 results in ”, not even close to the €, which is alt-E on my keyboard. So knowing what is the keyboard layout is important.

Comment: Took me about 20 seconds to select an US layout, press Alt-Shift-2 and get a € sign.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It is a QUERTY keyboard US layout.

Comment: Thanks, but I made a fool of my self already :(

Answer (score 8):

#### DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and enter

```
{ "$~2" = (insertText:, "₹"); }
```

This rebinds ⇧⌥2 to insert ₹
`$` = ⇧, `~` = ⌥

Quit and reopen applications for the change to take effect

Comment: This is more in keeping with the idiom of typing a sequence of keys and releasing them all at the same time to generate a special character. Using auto correction is OK if the shortcut is memorable and doesn't conflict with something you might type, like the actual word for instance.

Comment: This is great, the down side is it kills the €, but it might be ok if one does not uses that one.

Comment: @Buscar Indeed, the given shortcut was just an example.

Comment: @grgarside I really like the idea. I tried your code, but it doesnt work when I restart the application. Is the mapping correct.. One typo I found was the insertText: should also be surrounded by double quotes. The content of my `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` is     `{ "$~2" = ("insertText:", "₹"); }`

Comment: Great technique, but might be a bit complex for the average user...

Comment: Should that really be empty quotes? Or should the rupee symbol be inside the empty quotes?  This doesn't seem to work. I'm on 10.11.4 El Capitan.

Comment: How does it know to map to the rupee symbol if the insertText value is only ""?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe - In the double quotes on the right, do you have to put the rupee symbol in there or should it be empty?  I don't understand how this is supposed to work.  Thanks.  (It isn't working for me using either grgarside's method or yours.)

Comment: @jmort253 The value is not blank – seems your browser/font doesn't support the character as it's definitely there between the last pair of quotes.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the Text replace function.

[image: Rupee]

Now every time you type Rupee (or Rup, or what ever you like to use) in a text document it will be replace with the Rupee symbol.

This solution is my preference since there are No special finger breaking key combination, and nothing to remember.

Comment: Indeed there are hardly any layouts with the rupee sign assigned to a combination on OS X. This is probably the most convenient method.

Comment: How would you type the text in your answer with that shortcut in effect? Wouldn't it prevent the letters R-u-p-e-e from staying uncorrected wherever you typed them, no?

Comment: @bmike Rupee does not work inside webpage like this one, but it works everywhere else on my may mac, like Mail.app, TextEdit, Notepad, Calender, Finder file naming ect..

Comment: As noted by bmike, best to choose a non-word (Rup?) for your shortcut.

Comment: @TomGewecke It makes sense to do that :)

Answer (score 3):

There might be one if you are using a keyboard layout from around that part of the world (I don't know). Also, there might be an easier way to do this, I am not an expert.

1. go to System `Preferences > Keyboard`
2. click "Show Keyboard and Character Viewers in Menu Bar"
3. In the new menu bar item select "Show Character Viewer"
4. Select "Currency Symbols"
5. Right click the ₹ and select Copy Character Info
6. Paste this into Text Edit and then copy just the ₹ itself
7. Go back to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Text`
8. Click the `+` to add a new text replacement value
9. Pick a memorable but seldom used key combination (unfortunately here you cannot use modifier keys)

For the last step I used "rupee" which caused that symbol to appear while I was writing these instructions. (I then deleted it which is why I was able to type "rupee")

Comment: Heh, I didn't think that you already have the rupee character here in the question, so steps 1-6 aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: Well, this is not limited to US layouts.

Comment: @MaxRied good to know, I just didn't want to claim this would work if he had a different layout since I don't have one to try it on.

Answer (score 1):

Work through the following steps:

1. Go to System Preferences → Keyboard
2. Check ‘Show keyboard and character viewers in menu bar’
3. Open Microsoft Word → Preferences → AutoCorrect
4. In the **Replace:** column type `rs.`
5. Copy Paster the `₹` character.
6. In the **With:** column, right click and paste the copied `₹` character.
7. Alternatively, in the **Replace:** column, you can choose to input `®` character by pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> key and <kbd>r</kbd> button simultaneously.

[image: Input source menu bar item]

[image: Word preferences menu]

[image: AutoCorrect preferences 1]

[image: AutoCorrect preferences 2]

Comment: This works only for MS Word of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is because some Apps like Google Chrome do not use the Apple built-in text expansion feature but instead override it with their own keyboard handling mechanism. Usually, this is the reason why you cannot find those Apps that go against some default Apple's standards in the Appstore because they would be limited.

In the case of Chrome, there is little you can do about it since that is a closed source App and that is how it was made. However, there are a lot of add-ons in Chrome that do the exact same job, and sometimes even better with some more advanced features. Here is one.

What I personally recommend is using an external App for all your text expansions that work globally with all Apps. The one I have been using for a long time is TextExpander for Mac. You can try their free trial. It offers a lot of programmable expansions that come in handy in a lot of daily conversations/emails.

If you would like a free hack instead, try this:
When in Chrome just press (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), this will open the spotlight search bar, write your shortcut text, and it will expand after hitting space. Select it all (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), copy it (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), then hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and paste your full text (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) where you want to.
This workaround might seem a lot when reading it, but it is really a 2-second process when it sticks to your muscle memory.

Source: [How can OS X's Keyboard Text Replacement be used in all text entry fields within the OS?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-OS-Xs-Keyboard-Text-Replacement-be-used-in-all-text-entry-fields-within-the-OS)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a very old question but just wanted to contribute. It might still be helpful.

1. Please go to the keyboard settings on your Mac. **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Input Sources**.
2. Click on the plus (+) icon at the bottom-left corner.
3. Add **ABC - India** and select it if that is not the only one you have added.

[image: Screenshot of the System Preferences Keyboard Pane with the Input Sources tab selected]

4. Now, go to the **System Preferences** > **Language & Region**.
5. Set **India** as your region.
6. On the same screen, click on the plus(+) icon, add **English - India** and set it as your preferred language.
7. Then restart your machine (I had to do that).
8. Then by pressing <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, you should be able to type the ₹ symbol.

[image: Screenshot of the System Preferences Language & Region pane with the General tab selected]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Input Source for one of the languages of India, you can normally use <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.  Except Devanagari Qwerty, where it is on the <kbd>]</kbd>.

I do not know if this is region-specific or what, but it **does** work out of the box without editing any settings.

Answer (score -3):

Suggesting inserting a shortcut instead of editing the keyboard layout is IMAO a **horrible** suggestion.

Grab [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) and edit it properly™, instead.

i.e. if what you want to do is modify your keyboard layout, what you should actually do is... surprise surprise... modify your keyboard layout. Using workarounds such as those suggested is insane.

Comment: Ukelele is fine, but suggest you delete your pejorative comments about other solutions, there is really nothing wrong with them.

Comment: @TomGewecke IMAO yes, they are profundly wrong. What the OP actually wants to do is change the layout, so he should just change the layout. Doing strange workaround makes no sense under any point of view.

Comment: Would you mind describing in more details how the problem described by the OP could be solved with Ukelele? This would make for a more helpful answer.

Comment: @patrix nice idea! Cannot do it now but hopefully I'll edit it later.